# Поставить длинное тире (или линию)

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в метку поставить длинное тире (или линию)? Есть ли способы, кроме как рисовать вручную?

Comment: Сделать копи паст из таблицы символов?

Comment: Что такое "метка"?

Comment: Метка это TLabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alt + 0151

```
 ▲     
▲ ▲
```

Newfags cannot triforce

Comment: @leklerk
А как же кошерно трифорснуть напоследок?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое "кошерно трифорснуть". Прошу прощения.

Comment: Oldfags dont triforce